# Get date of 3 days ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL script that selects everything from current day.

```
SELECT  [ClientID] from [logs] where Date > CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())
```

Date is type of DateTime.

How to get everything within last 3 days? I suppose I need subtract 3 days from function `SYSDATETIME()` result, but how?

Comment: DATEADD(DAY,-3,CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()))

Answer (score 25):

```
SELECT  [ClientID] from [logs] where Date > DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()))
```

Comment: @vico hi, have you found answer?

Answer (score 14):

Use `GETDATE()` : Yes, it gets date from system!

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value
>   without the database time zone offset. This value is **derived from the
>   operating system of the computer** on which the instance of SQL Server
>   is running.

*Query:*

```
SELECT  [ClientID] from [logs] where ( Date  > GETDATE() - 3)
```

*More Reference:*

[**GETDATE Detailed Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql)

Comment: GetDate() gets the DateTime (i.e. date and time).

Answer (score 4):

For mysql use this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL - 3 DAY);
```

Comment: sql-server is not mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT ClientID 
FROM logs
WHERE Date BETWEEN SYSDATETIME() AND SYSDATETIME() - 3
```

Comment: got error "Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int"

Comment: See the answer here regarding to teh use of BETWEEN and Date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25564544/4654008

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
select * from Table where row > now() - INTERVAL 3 day;
```

So you can fetch all of 3 days ago!

Answer (score 0):

Using BETWEEN is nice. I also prefer the DATEADD function. But be aware of the fact that the SYSDATETIME function (or I would us GETDATE()) also includes the time which would mean that events before the current time but within the three day period may not be included. You may have to convert both sides to a date instead of datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [ClientID] from [logs] where Date > DATEADD(day, -3, SYSDATETIME())
```