# Comparing a Date column with a datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have found the below query in one our `stored procedures`

```
SELECT *FROM TABLE1
WHERE (CONVERT(DATE,DateTo) BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate))
```

Since Usage of `Functions` in `where` clause may hinder the performance I have changed it as below,

```
 SELECT *FROM TABLE1
 WHERE DateTo BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate
```

The result is same after changing the codes. But i am not sure whether both will give same result in all the time. Any Scenarios where the above codes bring different results?

> (P.S:  @wkstdate and @wkenddate are `DATE` values & DateTo is a
>   `DATETIME` value)

Appreciate Your Suggestions

Comment: you should use CONVERT(DATE,DateTo) BECAUSE MAKE sure in convert to DATE

Comment: previously answered question see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server/25564544#25564544

Comment: Do NOT use BETWEEN for date ranges, full stop (i.e. no exceptions). yes yes someone will point out you can cast to date and it works ok, but the general case you need to understand first. Best practice is to simply stop using between for date ranges. use a combination of >= with < (as shown at end of answer by Felix Pamittan, below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not yield the same result.

Let's say your `DateTo`, which is a `DATETIME` value, has a time component:

```
'2015-09-21 01:00:00'
```

Your `@wkenddate` is `'2015-09-21'`. The `WHERE DateTo BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate` will not retrieve the above row since `'2015-09-21 01:00:00'` > `@wkenddate`.

For more example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(DateTo DATETIME)
INSERT INTO tbl 
    SELECT CAST('2015-09-21 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2015-09-21 16:10:49.047' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2015-09-22 16:10:49.047' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2015-09-20 16:10:49.047' AS DATETIME) 

DECLARE  @wkstdate DATE = '20150921',
         @wkenddate DATE = '20150921'
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE DateTo BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate

SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE (CONVERT(DATE,DateTo) BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate)


DROP TABLE tbl
```

Now, using function in `WHERE` clause does make your query un-SARGable but there are exceptions. One of them is [`CAST`ing to `DATE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Another alternative if you do not want to `CAST` to `DATE` is to not use the `BETWEEN` operator. Instead use `>= and <`:

```
WHERE
    DateTo >= @wkstdate 
    AND DateTo < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @wkenddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BETWEEN` operator will not cope properly with Times on your date data.  So if you have two dates `1/1/2000` and `2/1/2000`, and then ask for `BETWEEN` to work on a datetime like `2/1/2000 14:00`, then this datetime does NOT fall between them.  Stripping the Time portion off the datetime is advisable, using your `CONVERT` function as in your example is probably the best way.  There are other ways to strip off the Time portion, but `CONVERT` is probably the most efficient. (My example using `dd/mm/yyyy` format)

What is the least efficient thing I noticed about your stored procedure is the use of `SELECT * FROM`. Try to use explicit field selections - to minimize the load on SQL if you want more efficient Stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both will give different results.

> Lets say wkStDate = 9/1/2015 and wkEndDta = 9/30/2015
>
> DateTo = 9/1/2015 18:00 HRS (will be included in both Cases)
>
> DateTo = 9/21/2105 18:00 HRS (will be included in both cases)
>
> DateTo = 9/30/2105 18:00 HRS (will be included in original query  but
>   excluded in second query without the convert)

In other words anyvalue where date part is same as end date and has time greater than midnight will be excluded from your query without the convert function i.e. WkEndDate + 00:00:01 To WkEndDate + 23:59:59 will be excluded. All other dates will show the same result.

If your DateTo is date time and will never has a time other than midnight then both the queries will give same result.