# MySQL now() value on datetime using date only

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a datetime field called LastChangeTimestamp that has a format like `2015-08-20 10:24:59`  I basically want to return all results from the current day back 7 days.  I've gotten to where I can use the now() command but am returning zero results I suspect because the system is trying to match the date and time down to the seconds back maybe?  How do I return records from the current date only (no time) using the datetime field and go back 7 days?

```
WHERE LastChangeTimestamp < unix_timestamp(now() - interval 7 day)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your column is in date format, you don't need to use `unixtimestamp`, you can just use [date_sub()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp) function to get the date 7 days ago, and compare to it:

```
WHERE LastChangeTimestamp > DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```