# Query previous day with GETDATE()-1 and a time period from/to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get total counts from `SuperScottTable1` from the previous day and narrow to a time frame (From-To). The below works fine until I add

```
AND (time > '08:00:00.000' AND time < '22:00:00.000')
```

It does not error, just returns null.

Is this possible to do?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(confirmedCount, 0))
FROM 
    SuperScottTable1
WHERE
    superLaneID = '90099' 
    AND time >= GETDATE()-1 
    AND (time > '08:00:00.000' AND time < '22:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Is time a time or a date time?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do to create a start and end datetime, and use those.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (GETDATE is product specific.)

Comment: Maybe try CAST/CONVERT ? Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: The time is the date/time as Gordon provided below, sorry about not defining that. I will try these and see how it goes. Sorry for late reply, I did not receive e-mail that there was any responses, I will check on that. Thx!

Comment: Is that column [time] date and time (datetime)? Are you still considering the solutions provided? Suggest you avoid using datepart() if you can, using functions on data in a where clause is a cause of poor query performance.

Comment: This is what I ended up using; SELECT SUM(COALESCE(confirmedCount,0))
FROM SorterLaneStatistics
WHERE
sorterLaneID = '90099' 
AND time >= DATEADD(hh, -12, GETDATE())

Comment: It seams to work good. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do some CAST/CONVERT shenanigans to generate a starting and stoping DATETIME value which you can then compare to your time column.  If the time column is indexed then this will allow the server to do a simple range search on the index to find matches.

```
WHERE
    superLaneID = '90099'
    AND time > CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 112) + ' 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)
    AND time < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 112) + ' 22:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `time` is stored as a `datetime`.  You seem to be using SQL Server, so you can extract the hour and use that:

```
WHERE superLaneID = '90099' AND
      time >= GETDATE()-1 AND
      datepart(hour, time) >= 8 AND
      datepart(hour, time) < 22
```

EDIT:  To get the "other" hours:

```
WHERE superLaneID = '90099' AND
      time >= GETDATE()-1 AND
      (datepart(hour, time) < 8 or
       datepart(hour, time) >= 22
      )
```

Comment: Gordon, this worked well! Thank you!! Also in advance as I am learning this and may have future questions.

Comment: Gordon, I know that;GETDATE()-1 AND
      datepart(hour, time) >= 5 AND
      datepart(hour, time) < 18 will get me 5am to 5pm. Is there anything special to get 5pm to 5am, wrapping around midnight. Will there be two statements needed, 1 for before midnight, and one from 12:00 to 5am?

Comment: Does this make any sense??   WHERE time >= GETDATE() AND
      datepart(hour, time) >= 5 AND
      datepart(hour, time) < 18

Answer (score 0):

GETDATE() in SQL Server returns the system date **and time** to arrive at the current day (i.e. date at time 00:00:00.0000000)  you can use either of these:

- cast(getdate() as date) -- available from SQL 2008 onward
- dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ),  0) -- any SQL Server version

Using these to establish the current date, then add (8-24) hours and or (22-24) hours to establish the boundaries of yesterday e.g.

```
WHERE superLaneID = '90099'
    AND time >= dateadd(hour,(8-24),cast(getdate() as date))
    AND time < dateadd(hour,(22-24),cast(getdate() as date))
```

Avoid using non-sargable predicates (such as using a function) that require you to alter each row of data to compare to a fixed value. ref [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server/25564544#25564544)

Btw: This method discussed here would work for a time range that spans midnight.