# SQL Date Range Query Issue

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-range

I am writing a SQL query to return matching items based on a set of criteria, one of which is to check todays date against a date range - stored as two seperate columns 'DateFrom' and 'DateTo'

My Query is as follows:

```
SELECT  
    A.* 
FROM 
    A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    B ON A.AlertID = B.AlertID 
WHERE
    A.AlertTypeID > 1 AND A.Active = 1 AND
    (B.Complete IS NULL OR B.Complete < 1) AND
    (A.DateFrom IS NULL OR 
    ((CONVERT(datetime, A.DateFrom, 103) <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 103) AND 
      CONVERT(datetime, A.DateTo, 103) >= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 103))))
```

This works fine if DateFrom and DateTo are different, but the issue I have is that I have an entry which has the same value in each, and it should be returned, but it is not.

Please can anyone advise on this one. Thanks.

Comment: `CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 103)` is the same value as `GETDATE()`  what is the goal here?

Comment: @JamieD77 - My apologies, I didn't see the `datetime` in `convert`

Comment: AND THEREIN LIES THE PROBLEM @MotoGP.

My code should be:

   (CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, A.DateFrom, 103), 103) >= CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103), 103) 
  AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, A.DateTo, 103), 103) <= CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103), 103)))

Comment: @Richard.Gale instead you can do this `cast(getdate() as date)`

Comment: @MotoGP does that trim the time off?

Comment: @Richard.Gale - yes it does

Comment: @MotoGP Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it was my own stupid fault, I normally cast the date to a varchar to trim off the time part, but as @MotoGP has now shown me a cleaner method for this, which I have gratefully adopted, my code now works and looks as follows:

```
    SELECT  
        A.* 
    FROM 
        A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        B ON A.AlertID = B.AlertID 
    WHERE
        AlertTypeID > 1 AND A.Active = 1 AND
        (B.Complete IS NULL OR B.Complete < 1) AND
        (A.DateFrom IS NULL OR 
        (CAST(A.DateFrom AS Date) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AND CAST(A.DateTo AS Date) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)))
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server/25564539#25564539

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 103)`, if you run this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 103)
```

You get:

```
2016-02-24 16:19:57.840
```

When I guess you only want to compare the date portion of the value, so you actually want:

```
2016-02-24
```

So use `DATE` instead in your convert:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 103)
```

This is only a quick mock-up of a piece of code using this logic, please test using your own data to verify:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      id INT ,
      datefrom DATETIME ,
      dateto DATETIME
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( id, datefrom, dateto )
VALUES  ( 1, '2016-02-02', '2016-02-28' ), -- will match
        ( 2, '2016-02-27', '2016-02-28' ), -- won't match
        ( 3, '2016-02-23', '2016-02-23' ), -- yesterday no match
        ( 4, '2016-02-24', '2016-02-24' )  -- today matches

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp A
WHERE   A.datefrom IS NULL
        OR ( (CONVERT(DATE, A.datefrom, 103) <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 103)
             AND CONVERT(DATE, A.dateto, 103) >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 103))
           )

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Produces:

```
id  datefrom                dateto
1   2016-02-02 00:00:00.000 2016-02-28 00:00:00.000
4   2016-02-24 00:00:00.000 2016-02-24 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, seems I causes the issue myself by not having my complete conversion in place to ensure I was only comparing dates (not date and time)