# to select range date of different of financial year - in different year - SQL

Tags: sql

I want to extract data based on FY2018-2019 and FY2022-2023 in one file

I tried this;

> where ( trunc (rep_date) <='01-jul-2018' and trunc (rep_date) >= '30-jun-2019')  ---- for FY2018-2019
>
> or ( trunc (rep_date)
> <='01-jul-2022' and trunc (rep_date) >= '30-jun-2023' )  ---- for
> FY2022-2023

Somehow result data for FY2022-2023 has a duplicate

I usually run extract data per each file for FY2018-2019 then change the date for FY2022-2023

is there an alternative way? or I stick to running each file?

thank you

Comment: your inequality signs appear to be the wrong way around; but no matter what you type in the WHERE clause you will not cause duplicates. They are either there already (in the table/view) or your join conditions are not correct.

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and tag your database system

Comment: nbk, thank you however i am not sure if I am using Oracle SQL part of RDBMS

Comment: @tinazmu, yes you are right other way round my mind so busy brainstorm how to get right date to get one file to execute to save me to running each file

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons it is best to avoid using functions on the data to suit a filtering conditions (i.e. here we want to avoid truncating the dates or timestamps). To help with this don't attempt to use the 30th June as the end point. Instead use **less than** 1st July **of the next year** as the end point and now you will not need to truncate the data at all: e.g:

```
WHERE (rep_date >= '2018-07-01' and rep_date < '2019-07-01') -- for FY2018-2019
   OR (rep_date >= '2022-07-01' and rep_date < '2023-07-01') -- for FY2022-2023
```

Now with respect to your database (which you didn't specify) you may need to use "date" in the syntax e.g.

```
WHERE (rep_date >= date '2018-07-01' and rep_date < date '2019-07-01') -- for FY2018-19
   OR (rep_date >= date '2022-07-01' and rep_date < date '2023-07-01') -- for FY2022-23
```

OR `to_date` or `to_timestamp` e.g:

```
WHERE (rep_date >= to_date('2018-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and rep_date < to_date('2019-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
   OR (rep_date >= to_date('2022-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and rep_date < to_date('2023-07-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Comment: thank you much Paul!! will try this one!!

Comment: actually I never use <= or >= cos sometime it confused.
I usually use 'between', like this trunc (rep_date) between '01-jul-2018' and '30-jun-2019'

Comment: NEVER use between for a date range.. ALWAYS use the combination of `>=` with `<` as shown above. I guarantee this is the most reliable , and best performing method.  Trouble with between is that it INCLUDES both the start and end into the result. But this is WRONG for a date range.

Comment: **Please** consider [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server/25564544#25564544) (it is in SQL Server syntax) but the logic remains true regardless of dbms. You really do **not** want to use **trunc** on every row of data as it will invariably consume more cpu (unecessarily) AND rob the query optimizer the ability to use an index on rep_date.

Comment: thank you for the explanation however my boss and colleagues are mainly using 'trunc' in our ORACLE SQL, I just go flow what's everyone coding  - shrug -

Comment: just letting you know your formula coding is perfect as I put ( ) for those range date with other combination ( non date, product, id etc). I am grateful your help and thank you very much!!

Comment: Yes, you would need other parentheses if adding further conditions to be met. Well done. Cheers.