SQL Server less than or equal to (<=) date not including last date
I have a what seems to be a simple but odd finding. When I use:
WHERE DateTime >= '2024-04-01' AND DateTime <= '2024-04-30'

This above only gives me up to 04/29, but not 04/30
WHERE DateTime >= '2024-04-01' AND DateTime < '2024-04-30'

This also only gives me up to 04/29, but not 04/30\
*And it is definitely not because 04/30 does not have any data, otherwise not need for bothering to post.
04/30 appears when I edit the WHERE to
AND DateTime < '2024-05-01'

And similarly if I use <= '2024-05-01', it also gives me up to 04/30 but not 05/01
Which is weird, why is <= treated the same way as <?
Thank you!

then there aren't aby that have vthat date, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

They are not the same. When using <= the value  2024-04-30 is only included if you have a DateTime value of '2024-04-30 00:00:00' exactly. Using < will exclude 2024-04-30 completely. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564482/how-to-compare-datetime-with-only-date-in-sql-server

That answers the concern! Thank you Bart!

Answering a question which is a duplicate is the wrong way unless there is a new,better way to solve the issue due to new functionality since the original question was answered. Otherwise, it makes the impression the question is no real duplicate or the answer tells anything new which is both untrue.

See also the SO guidelines. Each question that is a duplicate will be closed as soon as 3 persons voted to do so. Closed means no answer can be written. So if you see a question is a duplicate, provide the url to the original one and do not answer.

@Jonas Metzler There are 2 questions being answered here. One is why the operators appear to behave the same. The second implied question is how to avoid the issue. So I think you are at least half right.

See also https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

They are not the same. When using <= the value 2024-04-30 is only included if you have a DateTime value of '2024-04-30 00:00:00' exactly. Using < will exclude 2024-04-30 completely. See also How to compare datetime with only date in SQL Server.
